# Unfortunately the Apps has Stopped on certain android device

Tags: android, user-permissions

I am new to programming for android, I am developing an application similar to a Blog in android studio using Firebase. The app run smoothly on my android device but the app is closed immediately with the message "Unfortunately the Apps has Stopped" when using emulator and other android device. Attached below is Verbose log. No error from logcat.

Any idea of this matter wil be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**HomeActivity**

```
package com.example.android.myinsta;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private RecyclerView postList;

    private String userid;

    private boolean mLike = false;

    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CustomWord, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Like");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mFirebaseDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {


                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivityForResult(loginIntent,2);

                }
            }
        };

        postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayout.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayout.setStackFromEnd(true);

        postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);


    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CustomWord, PostViewHolder>(

                CustomWord.class,
                R.layout.activity_card,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, CustomWord model, int position) {

                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                viewHolder.setProfilePic(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfilePic());
                viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                viewHolder.setLike(post_key);

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mLike = true;
                        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (mLike) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                        mLike = false;


                                    } else {

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Random");
                                        mLike = false;

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.card_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Share button not yet implement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.card_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent commentActivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CommentActivity.class);
                        commentActivity.putExtra("commentID", post_key);
                        commentActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(commentActivity);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.card_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mLike = true;
                        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (mLike) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                        mLike = false;


                                    } else {

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Random");
                                        mLike = false;
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        if (postList.getAdapter() == null) {
            postList.swapAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter, true);
        } else {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {
            Intent blogIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, BlogActivity.class);
            startActivity(blogIntent);

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_setup) {
            Intent accountIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
            startActivity(accountIntent);

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout) {
            mAuth.signOut();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode != 2){
                HomeActivity.this.finish();

            } else {

            }
        }

}
```

**AndroidManisfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.myinsta">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"        />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/mylauncher"
        android:label="MYA"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity android:name=".BlogActivity"
            android:label="Add Post"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".CommentActivity"
            android:label="Comment"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.android.myinsta.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetupActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AccountActivity"
            android:label="Personal Account" />
        <activity android:name=".testActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

```
04-18 15:22:29.615 551-556/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 679K, 81% free 4830K/24284K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 4ms
04-18 15:23:39.605 692-692/? W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method setBrightness() with type int not found on target class class ha
04-18 15:23:39.605 692-692/? W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method getBrightness() with type int not found on target class class ha
04-18 15:23:39.615 475-811/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity bnds=[957,425][1168,551] (has extras)} from pid 692
04-18 15:23:39.625 692-692/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1137 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:370 com.vphone.launcher.Stats.recordLaunch:129 com.vphone.launcher.Launcher.c:3081 com.vphone.launcher.Launcher.onClickAppShortcut:3049 
04-18 15:23:39.635 692-5648/? V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1169169
04-18 15:23:39.645 692-696/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1667K, 29% free 5777K/8096K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 10ms
04-18 15:23:39.645 5649-5649/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-18 15:23:39.655 475-843/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.example.android.myinsta for activity com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity: pid=5649 uid=10044 gids={50044, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3003}
04-18 15:23:39.685 475-534/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10044, 1) failed with errno -13
04-18 15:23:39.735 692-692/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
04-18 15:23:39.745 5649-5649/com.example.android.myinsta D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-18 15:23:39.745 5649-5649/com.example.android.myinsta W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x94cd2b20)
04-18 15:23:39.755 475-794/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity
04-18 15:23:39.795 475-794/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1345K, 26% free 10593K/14152K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-18 15:23:39.805 475-488/? W/WindowManager: updateFocusedWindowLocked, focusedAppToken is null.
04-18 15:23:39.855 1040-1046/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 605K, 16% free 5129K/6056K, paused 1ms+15ms, total 28ms
04-18 15:23:40.305 692-692/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
04-18 15:23:40.305 692-5648/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1169841
04-18 15:23:40.305 475-488/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4aa826bc u0 com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity t18 f}
04-18 15:23:40.325 692-692/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-18 15:23:40.345 692-1236/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 52 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:23:40.375 692-1236/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(52) failed with errno -13
04-18 15:23:40.385 475-534/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10044, 0) failed with errno -13
04-18 15:23:40.385 692-1236/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 52 with tag 7d2bd33500000000(2100024117) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:23:40.385 692-1236/? I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocketFd(52, 2100024117, -1) failed with errno-13
04-18 15:23:47.715 707-710/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 16% free 3888K/4612K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
04-18 15:23:49.635 475-487/? E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{4ab68074 token=Token{4aa8276c ActivityRecord{4aa826bc u0 com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity t18}}} timed out
04-18 15:23:50.395 475-488/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4aa826bc u0 com.example.android.myinsta/.HomeActivity t18 f}
04-18 15:23:53.535 5649-5649/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5649 SIG: 9
04-18 15:23:53.535 475-794/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1123 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:9640 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash:9614 android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact:1311 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact:2071 
04-18 15:23:53.535 475-678/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.android.myinsta (pid 5649) has died.
04-18 15:23:53.545 475-485/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4aabb078 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4a973a84
04-18 15:24:05.365 1031-5895/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040700000000(805307399) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.385 156-498/? E/Drm: Failed to open plugin directory /vendor/lib/mediadrm
04-18 15:24:05.385 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 60 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.385 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 60 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.505 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 60 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.565 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 63 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.785 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 63 with tag 3000180300000000(805312515) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.785 2072-2082/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 60 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:05.795 2072-2082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 617K, 18% free 5735K/6992K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
04-18 15:24:06.465 2072-2075/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 818K, 18% free 5799K/6992K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
04-18 15:24:06.675 1031-1045/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 547K, 26% free 4580K/6124K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 4ms
04-18 15:24:06.715 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 65 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.735 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 68 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.785 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000040100000000(805307393) for uid 10007 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:06.795 1031-5898/? I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-13
04-18 15:24:08.545 475-538/? D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=0, published condition=0
04-18 15:24:13.615 551-556/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 604K, 81% free 4819K/24284K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
```

App run smoothly on my android device :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyZMw.png)

Unfortunately the app is closed on emulator and other device.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVui4.png)

All using the same apk file when install.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: "No error from logcat" -- look again. If you get the "Unfortunately, your app has stopped" error, there will be a Java stack trace (or, occasionally, a native stack trace) in LogCat associated with the crash.

Comment: "W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1137" this statement concerns me. I double-checked my code, i had never used any sendBroadCast at all.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your android emulator has google API on it. it is on binary image you want to run.

some link I found on the net:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/06/now-available-android-sdk-x86-system-image-with-google-apis